# Caesar Cipher With Space characters left unchanged

Tags: java, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to let the encryption function ignore the white spaces and the symbols between words from the UserInput. Should I use `isWhitespace` or what? and how to implement that?

The output for this program is totally correct, it shifts each letter to the next 7 one. but it doesn't accept shifting 2 words separated by space or coma.

I'm new into Java stunning world & I'm really enjoying it! Hence this's my 3rd week since I began.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test_Cipher{
    public static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, int shiftKey) {
        plainText = plainText.toLowerCase();
        String cipherText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
            char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            cipherText += replaceVal;
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to transpose **all** chars that you come across in the for loop, so you'll need an if condition in there. Why not try to first create this yourself and see what you can come up with? Also, please work on posting code that is better formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways of doing this: either create a positive match for the character or a negative one. In the positive match variant you first check if `plainText.charAt(i)` is a character that you want to keep, and in that case add it to the `cipherText` and `continue` with the loop.

In the other you can check if [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) returns `-1` indicating that the alphabet doesn't contain the character. In that case you do the same thing: add it and continue. This is the common method I've seen for the classic Ceasar "play" cipher:

```
// introduce a local variable, you don't want to perform charAt twice
char c = plainText.charAt(i);
int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(c);
// if charPositions is -1 then it is not found 
if (charPosition == -1) { // or define a constant NOT_FOUND = -1
    cipherText += c;
    // continue with the for loop
    continue;
}
```

Comment: It Worked.
Thanks a punch!